# JavaScript click() - not working more than once

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want to add auto-scrolling to header images here: https://listify-demos.astoundify.com/classic/listing/the-drake-hotel/

So `document.querySelector('.slick-next').click();` can do the click and I'm trying to get it working in a loop. Running the following in JS console:

```
function myscroller() {
    document.querySelector('.slick-next').click();
}

for (var i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
    myscroller();
}
```

I thought it's supposed to click the next button 10 times, but it clicks it only once. What's that I'm missing?

Comment: What is the 'click' supposed to do in your case? Do you have any example code?

Comment: It clicks the right button in the slider. The '>' thing.

Comment: Take a look here: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ slick has autoplay.

Comment: I'm assuming you'll have to wait for the slider animation to finish before clicking on the button does something else.

Comment: Also, unrelated side note: your loop iterates only 9 times.

Comment: The problem is because you're clicking the button 10 times in a matter of milliseconds. It will only have an effect after the transition completes. Have a look at the library you're using to see if it offers a method of moving directly to the Nth slide

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Generally speaking, the page is only redrawn after the execution of a thread. You'll probably find your function is emulating 10 clicks and then redrawing the page / performing the animation at the end of all that. Try using `window.setTimeout()` to make each click a separate process:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
    window.setTimeout(myscroller, i * 100); // each click 0.1 seconds apart
}
```

I've not tested this but I think as an alternative jQuery handles this quite well - if you tell it to emulate multiple events in a row, it actually waits for each one to finish before moving on to the next:

```
jQuery('#my_element').click().click().click() // etc
```

If you do try that approach I'd be interested to hear if it worked :)

Comment: jQuery doesn't do what you describe.

Comment: Well I did say it was untested. A downvote seems a bit harsh, you should find the first option in my answer works as required... by the way @bugnumber9 you might find your loop only executes 9 times as you're using `++i` instead of `i++` so it's incrementing it to 2 before the first iteration.

Comment: In fact, adding `window.setTimeout` worked :) Thanks a bunch Doug.

Answer (score -2):

For what I understand in your post. If the button is click it will loop 10 times right? `(correct me if i am wrong)`.. Here try this.

```js
function myscroller()
{
alert("Click Loop");
}
$("#btn").click(function(){
loopbtn();
});
function loopbtn(){
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
myscroller();
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click me">
```

Comment: On https://listify-demos.astoundify.com/classic/listing/the-drake-hotel/ when I click the next button (the '>' thing in the slider) - it scrolls one image. I want to perform multiple click with JS to make it look like auto scrolling.